# OpenCV 640x480 standard size?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

Quick easy question, why is 640x480 always the standard window width/height when getting a webcam stream? is this because most webcams have a viewable area of this size in pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all common webcams use a cheap image sensor, and *by far*, the most common sensors available on the market are available in two sizes: 320x240 (QVA) or 640x480 (VGA). Other types of sensors are uncommon *at best*, because they tend to be of either or both higher quality or simply more expensive to manufacture.

It's also difficult to transmit a live video stream at larger resolutions over a USB cable. USB simply isn't fast enough to support high-resolution, real-time, high framerate video.

If you need a larger image, you'll need to use a different kind of camera. You can find many available with resolutions like 1024x768, 1280x720, or perhaps larger. Most of these cameras are marketed for **industrial applications** or security. They tend to be fairly expensive (because large sensors are expensive to fabricate), but produce a better overall picture than common webcams do. They also usually use a different type of connection, like ethernet or some proprietary connection, purely to be able to handle the high data rate.

Comment: But the Pixel 2-D array(frame data) read in is based off of this Sensor Resolution correct?

Comment: In general, yes. It may also be scaled down in software by the driver to achieve higher frame rates.

Comment: Ok thanks, ya im using 640x480 for a Webcam-Mouse movement based on hand position, 640x480 seems to work well as standard (especially for laptop cameras)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it's the VGA size - it's very very common. For example, it's the lowest common denominator for all PC graphics cards. So it's very likely that a webcam will support this size.

Comment: Ah ok, so when we read in an image (in a 2-d array of pixels) it's by the camera 640x480 size?

Comment: Most webcams support several resolutions, exactly which ones varies. However it's very likely that 640x480 is supported.